# Parsing/stringify '<>' value from json

Tags: json, parsing, stringify

```
"newdynaid": 22,
"isPrimary": "Y",
"isNotNull": "Y",
"scalePrecision": "",
"checkConstraint": "(ABC<>(0))",
"isUnique": "N",
"name": "INDV_ID",
"sizeUnits": "",
"foreignConstraint": "",
```

I have the above json snippet that needs to be displayed on the JSP as is. I have tried both stringify and parse options to consider '<>' as a string value and not terminate the JSON string after this but unable to do so. 
@BalusC, I hope you could help me there.

Comment: Please try to explain more clearly what you are trying to do. I have no idea. What does "consider '<>' as a string value" mean?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, which I don't understand, try inserting that string into the DOM as the `textContent` attribute of an element, rather than as `innerHTML`, which will treat it as HTML, and interpret the `<>`.

Answer (score 0):

The last comma is going to be a problem. Furthermore, I am unsure what you are trying to do. This is my best guess:

```js
var data={"newdynaid": 22,
"isPrimary": "Y",
"isNotNull": "Y",
"scalePrecision": "",
"checkConstraint": "(ABC<>(0))",
"isUnique": "N",
"name": "INDV_ID",
"sizeUnits": "",
"foreignConstraint": ""};

function show() {
  document.getElementById("out").textContent=JSON.stringify(data).replace(/,/g,",\n");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Show" onclick="show();"><pre id="out"></pre>
```